# What are generators of a module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Are those the basis of a module (so that every element of a module is a linear combination of those elements aka "generators")?

Or are those the elements from the set from which our given module was generated, i.e.

$$M=\bigcap _{A\subset M_n}M_n \text{   where $M_n$ are modules, and
  $A=\left\{a_1,\:...,\:a_s\right\}$ $\ni$ $a_i$ are generators of module M}$$

Or are those two concepts the same thing in the end?

Answer (score 0):

For a module $M$ to have a basis $E$ it must be a free module (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_module) this means that any element of your module can be written as a linear combination of these basis elements and these basis elements cannot be written as a linear combination of all other basis elements. Though its important to remember that the coefficients in the linear combination are now elements of the ring $R$ for which $M$ is an $R$-module.

Following the wikipedia definition a subset $E = \{e_{i}\}$ of module $M$ over ring $R$ is a basis if:

1. For any $m\in M$ there exists an ordered list of values $\{r_{i}\}$ from ring $R$ such that:
   $$m = \sum_{i} r_{i} \cdot e_{i}$$
2. If we pick a set of values $\{r_{i}\}$ and find that
   $$\sum_{i} r_{i} \cdot e_{i} = 0_M$$
   then we picked $r_{i} = 0_{R} \forall i$, where $O_{M}$ and $O_{R}$ are the additive identities of module $M$ and ring $R$ respectively.